# Connect Microsoft SQL Server 2012 with a spinner box in eclipse,

Tags: android, sql-server-2012

I am able to connect to my SQL Server 2012 from my Android app and view the results in LogCAT in eclipse, What I am trying to do is to get the results in a android spinner.

```
 try{
    Log.i("Android"," MySQL Connect Example.");
    Connection conn = null;

    String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    //test = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class;
    String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxxx:1433;user=admin;password=admin;";
    String username = "admin";
    String password = "admin";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
    Log.w("Connection","open");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from test");

   //Print the data to the console
    while(reset.next()){
  //    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.employee);
    Log.w("DataData",reset.getString(2));
    }
    conn.close();
} catch (Exception e)
{ 
    e.printStackTrace();
```

Like I say, I can connect to the server and is able to see the results in the log, But want to add to spinner, Not sure how to get from the `while(reset.next()){` to a spinner.

Comment: 1. don't do this (do not use jdbc directly on android platform) on windows platform i would use some WCF REST service for this 2. search for Adapters tutorials ... (you need to ArrayList<String> where you put all data in this loop then you should use it with ArrayAdapter<String>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it... Just had to change this part:

```
while(reset.next()){
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.employee);
Log.w("DataData",reset.getString(2));
```

to:

```
if(room!=null){
     do {

            RoomData.add(new RoomListDB(room.getString(3)));
        } 
            while(room.next());{
        }
```